# DNS Probe Possible, dig cannot find servers, problem happens intermittently

Tags: dns, tor

Ubuntu 22.04

I first discovered this problem when my Brave browser would occasionally report `DNS_PROBE_POSSIBLE`. However, it isn't just a browser issue. It happens at unpredictable times and there is no way to know how long it will last. When it happens, I can't use the Brave Browser or `dig`, but my Signal messaging app still works.

```
$ dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.18.1-1ubuntu1.3-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I had been using `Stubby`, so I thought maybe that might be intermittently causing the problem. So I shut down Stubby and switched back to `systemd-resolved`. That did not work.

Another computer on my local network (which is running Debian) still has working DNS, so my ISP's DNS server is still working.

I also run `tor` on this system. I shut down tor, but that did not work either.

But here is the weird thing. I can access the Internet with the Tor Browser which is how I am posting this question. I assume the Tor Browser uses its own DNS servers or something. But I need a working DNS system and I still have not figured out what is causing this.

I am not using a `VPN` or `iptables` at this time.

Does anyone know what the problem could be, how to fix it or how I might figure out what is causing it?